# PYSPARK- find top n records for every month using core spark api's

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My sorted RDD with count close to 50 k is as per below 
format of rdd : (date, (customer_id, subtotal)) data as per below.
How can i extract top 5 customers for each date in the above RDD using 
core Spark. 
any pointers on implementing rank in core spark would also help.``

`for i in orderItemsJoinSortMap.take(10): print(i)`

```
('2013-07', (5293, 2781.73))
('2013-07', (4257, 2059.75))
('2013-07', (32, 2009.75))
('2013-07', (5182, 1949.8200000000002))
('2013-07', (1478, 1784.7600000000002))
('2013-07', (1175, 1699.91))
('2013-07', (9807, 1664.9))
('2013-07', (1780, 1651.8500000000001))
('2013-07', (11941, 1649.8000000000002))
('2013-07', (2071, 1629.8400000000001))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions in the spark sql module, there several enumerating functions in the module.

First you'll need to convert your RDD to a dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DoubleType, StringType
schema = StructType([
    StructField("date", StringType()), 
    StructField("col", StructType([
        StructField("customer_id", IntegerType()), 
        StructField("subtotal", DoubleType())
    ]))])
my_rdd = sc.parallelize([('2013-07', (5293, 2781.73)),('2013-07', (4257, 2059.75)),('2013-07', (32, 2009.75)),
                         ('2013-07', (5182, 1949.8200000000002)),('2013-07', (1478, 1784.7600000000002)),
                         ('2013-07', (1175, 1699.91)),('2013-07', (9807, 1664.9)),('2013-07', (1780, 1651.8500000000001)),
                         ('2013-07', (11941, 1649.8000000000002)),('2013-07', (2071, 1629.8400000000001))])
df = my_rdd.toDF(schema)
df.printSchema()

    root
     |-- date: string (nullable = true)
     |-- col: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- customer_id: integer (nullable = true)
     |    |-- subtotal: double (nullable = true)
```

Now we can define our window frame and apply the window function:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("date").orderBy(psf.desc("col.subtotal"))
df = df.withColumn("rn", psf.row_number().over(w))
df.show()

    +-------+--------------------+---+
    |   date|                 col| rn|
    +-------+--------------------+---+
    |2013-07|      [5293,2781.73]|  1|
    |2013-07|      [4257,2059.75]|  2|
    |2013-07|        [32,2009.75]|  3|
    |2013-07|[5182,1949.820000...|  4|
    |2013-07|[1478,1784.760000...|  5|
    |2013-07|      [1175,1699.91]|  6|
    |2013-07|       [9807,1664.9]|  7|
    |2013-07|[1780,1651.850000...|  8|
    |2013-07|[11941,1649.80000...|  9|
    |2013-07|[2071,1629.840000...| 10|
    +-------+--------------------+---+
```

And finally you can filter on the top 5 customers for each date:

```py
df.filter("rn >= 5")
```